# Powershell securestring containing comma, or ? or : not working

Tags: powershell

I've a script to convert a string to a securestring, to use it in a powershell script.

The script works fine, but I'm not able to use password when there is a comma , or ? or : (I don't know which of the special char don't work ....) inside.

Here is the script :

```
# Creating SecureString object

$PasswordFile = "X:\pwd\password.txt" # where the securestring will be stored

$KeyFile = "X:\pwd\password.key" # where the AES.Key is located

$Key = Get-Content $KeyFile

$Password = "azerty,12?34:5" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force # put your password

$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $Key | Out-File $PasswordFile
```

Thanks

I already tried a lot of escape sequences,
`'''password'''`,
backslash, ....

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, are you sure the key is correct? When you say unable to use the password, what does it mean exactly ?

Comment: `Out-File` defaults to encoding UTF-16LE in PowerShell 5.x and below. Perhaps the problem lies there? Try using `Set-Content` instead.